# Which CSS properties affect only layout, either directly or indirectly?

Tags: css

I'm trying to compile a list of all of the CSS properties that affect only layout.
What I want to do is replace an element with a new element, apply all of the layout affecting CSS properties of the element to be replaced to the new element and remove those properties from the element to be replaced and then insert the element to be replaced into the new element.

The short version is that I want to wrap an element in a container and preserve it's position/layout on the page.

So far I have

```
height: parent;
width: parent;
top: parent;
left: parent;
margin: parent;
padding: parent;
display: parent;
float: parent;
box-sizing: parent;
z-index: parent;
```

[image: wrapping an element diagram]

I'm creating a solution to a long standing problem of mine; Not having the ability to display tooltips on a touch device. The idea is to let someone create an element that can be dragged to indicate whether a user wants information about the button or to initiate the default action of the button. I obviously want to let a user style the button/element but I also need to wrap it in a container so that I can insert other elements like the boundary in my example into the group and position it relative to the button. A very incomplete demo can be seen here -> http://plnkr.co/edit/R6udMO?p=preview (You will need a touch device to use it)

Comment: Depending on what you mean by layout, http://csstriggers.com might be it.

Comment: That's awesome, I think I might be going at this from the wrong angle though.